# spark-shell error: value builder is not a member of object com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, spark-shell

I'm just getting started with EMR Hadoop/spark etc., I am trying to use spark-shell to run a scala code to upload a file to EMRFS S3 location however I am receiving below error -

Without any Import If I run =>

```
val bucketName = "bucket"
val outputPath = "test.txt"

scala> val putRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder.bucket(bucketName).key(outputPath).build()
<console>:27: error: not found: value PutObjectRequest
   val putRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder.bucket(bucketName).key(outputPath).build()
                    ^
```

Once I add the Import package for PutObjectRequest I still get a different error.

```
scala> import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest
```

import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest

```
scala> val putRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder.bucket(bucketName).key(outputPath).build()
<console>:28: error: value builder is not a member of object com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest
   val putRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder.bucket(bucketName).key(outputPath).build()
                                     ^
```

I'm not sure what I am missing. Any help would be appreciated!

Note: Spark version is 2.4.5

Comment: Refer AWS documentation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html

Comment: @hagarwal I couldn't get this working in scala (spark-shell)

Comment: Exactly what problem are you facing while executing it?

Comment: @hagarwal I am getting this error: value builder is not a member of object com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest (Posted error message in the question as well above for reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the builder create the object of PutObjectRequest via a suitable constructor. Also, create a connection to S3 using AmazonS3ClientBuilder.

```
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest

import java.io.File

val clientRegion = Regions.DEFAULT_REGION
val bucketName = "*** Bucket name ***"
val fileObjKeyName = "*** File object key name ***"
val fileName = "*** Path to file to upload ***"

val s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard.withRegion(clientRegion).build

// Upload a file as a new object with ContentType and title specified.
val request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileObjKeyName, new File(fileName))
val metadata = new ObjectMetadata()
metadata.setContentType("plain/text")
metadata.addUserMetadata("title", "someTitle")
request.setMetadata(metadata)
s3Client.putObject(request)
```